# How to run a script from the host inside a vagrant guest in a single step?

Tags: vagrant

Currently it takes 3 steps to run the script I want in the guest:

```
vagrant ssh
cd /vagrant
composer test
```

Is there a way of running `composer test` from the host machine inside the guest in a single step?

I could add the 3 steps to a vagrant provisioning script so they get run automatically on `vagrant up`. But, I want to be able to run `composer test` multiple times from the host during a single vagrant session and ideally without having to ssh into it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `ssh`, `vagrant ssh` has a `-c` [flag](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh.html#c-command) to run command directly, so you can do:

```
vagrant ssh -c "cd /vagrant && composer test"
```

Comment: I had to upgrade to vagrant 2.2 for this to work. There's a bug in version 2.1.5 by the looks of it.

Comment: This is wierd, there is nothing on the [changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/v2.2.0/CHANGELOG.md) about it. But at least the latest version is working.